# How can I fix half div background issue

Tags: html, css

My `<div>` background is shows half how can I fix it.
It shift all my background images to left and half right goes white in IE

here is screenshots

http://scrshots.blogspot.in/2014/11/1st-screen-shot.html

Comment: Please don't write your title in all-caps. It won't gain your question better attention. (In fact, it'll probably do quite the opposite..)

Comment: Don't post in all caps !

Comment: “my div bg is shows half” — could you explain what you mean by that in more detail? Or maybe show us a picture?

Comment: Compare the size of your image and size of your div tag.

Comment: when i  add image to div background and i applied it 100% width it working properly in mozila and crome but in IE it aliend my background image to left and right side goes white.hope you undestand

Answer (score 1):

If it's a background for whole page try to attache it to body. If it shows only half of image most common problem is something mixed up with divs. If you have more background images try to provide a frame for them (separatly) using divs. Also are you sure that position should be absolute not relative?

```
body {
background: url(main-bg.jpg) no-repeat
}
```

Comment: freecharge.in this website which i am creating there is multiple background images and yes i applied all background to to different divs please check the website

Comment: I don't see any problems with backgrounds.

Comment: no sir that is website which i am trying to create this not my website

Comment: there is  images like "girl image and a male with iphone etc" these background images i was talking about mine is going to left in IE

Comment: i tried put screenshot but it's show i have to have reputation 10 for posting images and i am new here so hope you understand

Comment: hey i posted my html code also now please check it out and help me to solve this

Comment: visit this link for screent shot                                     http://scrshots.blogspot.in/2014/11/1st-screen-shot.html